# MongoDB: I have an array with documents containing an ID. How can I fill the rest of the document with the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which has an array bundleArticles. The array itself holds a list of articles. At first the article contains just the ID.

How can I fill up the rest of the article by using the aggregation framework?

First step would be to look up the articles with a lookup query but then I have an object containing all 4 articles.
How do I fill up the original array with the correct articles?

Here's an input document:

[image]

I would like the bundleArticles.x.article property to be filled up with the details of that article. So shortdescription etc are not null but the values of that article.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it and add input and output examples?

Answer (score 0):

I have this aggreagate right now:

This is a step in the right direction but I now end up with only having an _id and the bundleArticles Property due to the group statement.

```
db['products.articles.r092'].aggregate([
{ "$match" :  { "bundleArticles": { "$gt": [] } } },
{ "$unwind": "$bundleArticles" },
{ "$lookup" : { "from" : "products.articles.r092", "localField" : "bundleArticles.article.id", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "bundleArticles.tempArticle" } },
{ "$unwind": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle" },
{ "$addFields": {
    "bundleArticles.article": {
        "id": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle._id",
        "identifiers": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.identifiers",
        "type": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.type",
        "slug": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.slug",
        "name": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.name",
        "shortDescription": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.shortDescription",
        "imageUrl": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.imageUrl",
        "properties": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.properties",
        "price": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.price",
        "discount": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.discount",
        "parentCategorySlugs": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.parentCategorySlugs",
        "variations": "$bundleArticles.tempArticle.variations"
    }
   }
},
{
  "$project": { 
    "bundleArticles.tempArticle": 0
  }
}
,
{
  "$group": {
    _id: "$_id",
    bundleArticles: {
        "$push": "$bundleArticles"
    }
  }
}
])
```